# Combined pagination between 2 models in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I have 2 models:  `Restaurant`, and `Venue`.

All Venues can host events, and some Restaurants can host events.

I want to make a paginated list of places that can host events - example:

```
1) Venue
2) Restaurant
3) Venue
4) Venue
...etc
```

Is there a way to do this?  Have a paginated results set that combines data from 2 models?

Venues and Restaurants are not related other than both belonging to 'City'.

Comment: It may require some customization, but you may be able to do this using the UNION syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, use the `UNION` statement in MySQL. Create a custom paginate and paginateCount function in your model as described here:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination

Then you can create a custom find that will paginate your results for you.

Comment: See this link for more about `UNION`